# Wait and notify on an object not working as I expected

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I have a java servlet and am using jetty. On receiving a POST request, I am trying to send out another request to a different service. Upon receiving a response from the other service, I want to wake up my thread and continue sending the response. I am trying to use an object 'lock' to wait and notify. Can anyone tell why my thread doesn't wake up on lock.wait()?

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    Object lock = new Object();

    client.newRequest("http://localhost:3699/create")
            .method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .content(new StringContentProvider(ServletUtils.extractRequestBody(request)))
            .send(new BufferingResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Result result) {
                    ServletUtils.forwardResponse(response, result, getContentAsString());
                    System.out.println("NOTIFY");
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        lock.notifyAll();
                    }
                    System.out.println("DONE NOTIFICATION");
                }
            });

    try {
        System.out.println("WAIT");
        lock.wait();
        System.out.println("DONE WAITING");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        ServletUtils.badRequest(response);
    }
}
```

My print statements say

```
WAIT
WAIT
NOTIFY
DONE NOTIFICATION
```

a) I'm not sure why I get 2 WAIT

b) I don't get to DONE WAITING

Comment: Your method should throw an exception, since you try to call wait() without owning the monitor of the object. You're also supposed to always call wait inside a loop checking for a condition. Read the javadoc. It explains all of that. You should use a higher-level abstraction, like a CountDownLatch

Comment: Output the request.getDispatchType() and request.getRequestURI() during your WAIT output too.

Comment: Why complicate things with wait/notify? Either use AsyncContext (what its designed for) and/or hook up the Client async I/O to the Servlet Async I/O.